# The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian Continuum Release' does not have a Release file. - MX Linux 18.3

Tags: linux, docker

I have been following the instructions on [Get Docker Engine - Community for Debian](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/) in attempts to add the Docker repo.  I have tried a number of combination, but always get the " does not have a Release file" message for whatever release I put in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`

I have viewed the related SO question for Ubuntu [Docker Repository Does Not Have a Release File on Running apt-get update on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41133455/docker-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file-on-running-apt-get-update-on-ubun/43639310)

I ran the two following commands to add the key, which I think is correct

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -C
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
```

I have tried using Continuum, trusty, xenial, bionic, etc.  Yeah, I believe most of those names are for Ubuntu so they aren't going to work.  Continuum was found by executing `lsb_release -cs`.  Does anyone have any idea what I should use so I can use apt to install Docker on MX Linux 18.3?  Thanks!

Specific error message is

```
Err:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian Continuum Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian Continuum Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```